# Eigen evaluation with an auto hits temporal

Tags: c++, eigen, auto

I am trying to perform an evaluation in Eigen.

```
        const Eigen::Vector3d position = m_rigidBody->pos().segment<3>(0); // pos() returns a const `Eigen::VectorXd &`
        const Eigen::Quaterniond &rotation = m_rigidBody->rot();

        const auto p = rotation * m_r + position; // Lazy evaluation, but rotation, m_r and position are always available afaik

        const auto skew = [](const Eigen::Vector3d &v) -> Eigen::Matrix3d {
            return Eigen::Matrix3d{{0, -v[2], v[1]},  //
                                {v[2], 0, -v[0]},
                                {-v[1], v[0], 0}};
        };

        MapType j = MapType::Zero();
        j.block<3, 3>(0, 0).setIdentity();
        j.block<3, 3>(0, 3) = skew((-(p - position)).eval()); // here it hits the temporal and crashes
        return j;
```

AFAIK the `const auto p` is just an expression template describing the operation, and it has to store the values that it operates on. Those values, afaik, exists when the operation is requested.

On the `(-(p - position)).eval()` the program crashes, according to sanitizers, trying to access a wrong location.

However, I dont get why. All the values should be still alive. Any idea why this is wrong?

I have prepared a minimal reproducible example in godbolt, adding the sanitizers which show the issue:
https://godbolt.org/z/7r9PEjeGM

I have tested using the quaternion * vector, which fails. If using matrix * vector, then it works fine.

Comment: What is MapType? What is ```m_r```? Preferably turn this into minimum reproducible example but I'd be happy just knowing what we're looking at.

Comment: MapType id a Matrix<double, 3, 6> and m_r is a Vector3d. I can share later a reproducible example

Comment: I have added a reproducible example

Comment: So I have been testing a bit, and apparently when using the M*r + p, anything is evaluated, but when using rotation*r + p, the rotation*r is being evaluated inmediately into a temporary, which triggers the issue. Isnt this a bug?

Comment: Yeah, I was suspecting that we mix eager and lazy evaluation here. I wouldn't really call it a bug though. Eigen explicitly warns against auto and most of its design predates auto's existence. I'll have to come up with save(ish) guidelines for using auto but that involves language lawyering and looking at Eigen's implementation. Ugh … One thing is clear however: If you make every operation its own auto variable, things cannot go wrong. It's just very verbose

Comment: Yeah, that becomes too verbose. I would could it a bug because it kind of breaks Eigen style of returning an expression. Here it just evaluates the rotation * vector, instead of returning an expression to perform the operation later :-s In any case, reading Eigen implementation, I found that it recommends using a rotation matrix for applying the transform so... I have moved to use a matrix, which returns an expression

Comment: And yeah, Eigen warns about using auto unless you know what you are doing. I was completely sure I know what I was doing in this case, except apparently I wasnt

Comment: I have the same feeling. I saw your question and immediately went Oh sh…

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the day, many operations in Eigen return temporaries which hold references to their input arguments.  These are usually referred to as expression templates.  It is generally unsafe to use auto to capture such a result, as it can result in dangling references.

This is documented at https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html

In particular, I suspect that is the line you've identified
 `const auto p = rotation * m_r + position`

The problem is this is evaluated as `(rotation * m_r) + position`.  The result of the multiplication could be a temporary value (it could either be lazy, or fully evaluated.  I can't recall if eigen lazily does multiplication).  In either case, the result is a temporary object, which we can call `multResult`.

However, `multResult + position` is certainly going to return an expression template which has references to the temporary multResult, as well a reference to position.

When you save that via `const auto p = ...`, the temporary multResult is deleted at the end of the expression, and you now have a dangling reference.

Your solution is to save it to proper variable, or use the `.eval()` to evaulate the entire expression:

`const auto p = (rotation * m_r + position).eval();`

Comment: I see! So I wanted to avoid evaluating it, as I dont want to perform unnecessary writes. I thought that it would generate a Sum(Multi(rot, m_r), position), which shouldnt have temporaries, but I see the Multi itself is a temporary.

Comment: So, given that expression templates can avoid performing unecessary operations or writes, how could I benefit from it in this particular case, for example?

Comment: Well, in this particular case, you could save it to an Eigen::Vector3d.  When you use it in the p - position, which is passed to skew, it's going to get assigned to a vector3d prior to being passed to the lambda.  But, in the general sense, save it to a real type (i.e. Eigen::Vector3d or Eigen::MatrixXd), or use the .eval() on the entire expression, and let eigen figure out the correct type.  Or just make one very large expression, which does as much as possible all at once.

Comment: The point was to avoid saving it to an intermediate variable. And I thoguht I coulf use auto for that